# universal Link not redirecting to my ios app

Tags: swift

I'm working on universal link first time i have set all needed things but URL not opening my Mobile app. My server side file is with specific folder and with out folder 
[image]

[image]

My Xcode settings is 
[image]

My App entitlement file Target membership also selected
[image]

Link which i want to open
[image]

My Appstore BundleID, prefix and configuration 
[image]

My app url on server is https://beta-dev.callingdr.com:92/patient

Every thing is good but URL is open web app in safari not opening internal mobile app i don't no what is wrong. Help me out. I know its duplicate question but not any answer is helping me out.

Thanks

Comment: Don't know what i'm doing wrong kindly help me out. Thanks

Comment: Any solution. I have same issue with iOS 12.2 version it works well in iOS 11

Answer (score 1):

I think your hosting url is not proper.

**According to apple documentation:**

After you create the `apple-app-site-association` file, upload it to the `root` of your HTTPS web server or to the `.well-known` subdirectory. The file needs to be accessible via HTTPS—without any redirects—at `https://<domain>/apple-app-site-association` or `https://<domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`. Next, you need to handle universal links in your app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

My suggestion:

`https://beta-dev.callingdr.com:92/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`

or

`https://beta-dev.callingdr.com:92/apple-app-site-association`

Comment: i already done https://beta-dev.callingdr.com:92/apple-app-site-association

Comment: delete your app and reinstall it